# save new data to wp_options non-post form

Tags: database, wordpress

have a form on my front-page. It sends the entered address to Google API and returns the JSON to wp_options. That works fine. I am using update_option to do that, so it rewrites the meta_key each time. How would I go about having each address entered remain?

```
$address = esc_html( $_POST['address'] );

  //assign JSON object to var using  geocodeing function('address') input 
  $address_results = gmap_geocode($address);

  // transfer data to options array
  $options['py_name'] = $py_username;
  $options['address'] = $address;
  $options['coords']  = $address_results;

  // create and name the option_name and set fields with $options array
  update_option( 'row_name', $options );
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to encode or serialize array before updating into options table

json encode as follows.

```
$newoption = json_encode($options);
update_option( 'row_name', $newoption);
```